# How to read data from text file using pandas in a specific format?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file which contains data as below.

```
20/12/2018 
This is the test text. 

22/12/2018
* 21/12/2018 
This is a test text where the text is written on later than the actual date.
```

Now let say, the above data with the dates in a text file (text.txt). I need a way to read that data and put it on a pandas data frame. I want to read them into the columns as,

Date Text DateOfWritten

The date will take the take which should be the actual date of the text. For example, 
21/22/2018 should be the date. And 22/12/2018 should be DateOfWritten

The expected output should be something like:
[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check `pd.to_datetime` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html). bdw can you please provide a sample dataframe and an expected output for a full answer. Thanks

Comment: @anky_91 thanks for your quick response. I have added the desired output data frame and more information. Hope this will help.

Comment: The formatting of the file(not the expected output) doesnot make any sense to me, are you sure the pattern is the same as you have provided ?

Comment: Yeah, I am sure about that. This is kinda weird format. But I am facing that.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one solutions

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

dict_for_df = defaultdict(list)
last_find = None
last_date = None

with open("test.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        curr_find = line.find("/")
        if line == "\n":
            continue
        elif curr_find == 2:
            Date = line.replace("\\n","").strip()
            dict_for_df['DateOfWritten'].append(Date)
            last_date = Date
            last_find = 2
        elif (last_find == 2 and  curr_find != 4):
            dict_for_df['Date'].append(last_date)
            dict_for_df['text'].append(line.replace("\n","").strip())
            last_find = 0
            last_date = ''
        elif curr_find == 4:
            dict_for_df['Date'].append(line.replace("*","").replace("\n","").strip())
            last_date = ""
            last_find = None
        else:
            dict_for_df['text'].append(line.replace("\n","").strip())
            last_date = ""
            last_find = None

df =  pd.DataFrame(dict_for_df)
```